# Getting a list of users from a mysql table

Tags: php, mysql

I have a MySQL table that consists of the following data:

```
User  | Status 
------|-------
Bob   | online  
Mike  | online  
Karen | offline  
Joe   | online
```

Is there a way to form a query like the one below, so that I get back a list of all users who are online?

```
$query=  "SELECT User FROM User_table WHERE Status='online'";
$db->setQuery($query);
$userlist=$db->loadresult();
```

Comment: Um, you mean like your query will do?

Comment: Did you try your query?

Comment: I added my php code above.  Only returns 1 user.

Comment: are you using Joomla?

Answer (score 0):

I am supposing that you are using Joomla, since I found the functions `$db->setQuery()` and `$db->loadResult()` in the jDatabase' documentation.

In this case, please note that [$db->loadResult()](http://docs.joomla.org/JDatabase/loadResult) only returns the first result (and that too a particular column).

You will have to loop through to get all the records:

```
$userlist = array();
$query=  "SELECT User FROM User_table WHERE Status='online'";
$db->setQuery($query);
$results = $db->loadObjectList();
foreach ($results as $row) {
  $userlist[] = $row->User;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

$db->loadResult() only loads one record.  To get another record, simply call it again.

Reference: http://docs.joomla.org/J1.5:Accessing_the_database_using_JDatabase

> Each of these results functions will return a single record from the
>   database even though there may be several records that meet the
>   criteria that you have set. To get more records you need to call the
>   function again.

Or you can use the `$db->loadRowList()` which will return an indexed array of indexed arrays, namely all rows, and columns of your query.